# Plotting time series in Stata: change label of dates?

Tags: date, plot, stata

I want to plot a time series in Stata.

I have a csv file (file.csv) that looks like

```
v1            v2
01/01/2000    1.1
01/02/2000    1.2
01/03/2000    1.3
01/04/2000    1.4
01/05/2000    1.5  
01/06/2000    1.6
01/07/2000    1.7
01/08/2000    1.8
01/09/2000    1.9
01/10/2000    1.10
01/11/2000    1.11
01/12/2000    1.12
```

In order to plot the time series in Stata I do:

```
clear all
*import data 
import ...fil.csv

*adjust dates
gen Time_temp = date(v1, "MDY")
format Time_temp %tm
gen Time = mofd(Time) 
label variable Time "Time"
format Time %tm
tsset Time
drop Time_temp

*1) Assign a label to v2
label variable Price "Monthly price ($)"
*2) plot time series of v2 with the median, mean, min, max
egen median_v2 = median(Oil_price)
egen mean_v2=mean(v2)
egen min_v2 = min(v2)
egen max_v2=max(v2)
label variable median_v2 "Median ($)"
label variable mean_v2 "Mean ($)"
label variable min_v2 "Min ($)"
label variable max_v2 "Max ($)"
twoway tsline v2 || tsline median_v2 || tsline mean_v2 || tsline min_v2 || tsline max_v2, xlabel(2000m1 "Jan2000" 2000m3 "March2000" 2000m12 "Dec2000", angle(vertical)) xmtick(##12)
```

I get as error: `invalid label specifier, :  2000m1 "Jan2000" 2001m3 "March2000" 2001m12 "Dec2000"`. Could you help me to fix this?

Comment: Two specific errors here: assigning a monthly date display format to a daily date won't change it to a monthly date; strings like `2000m1` can't serve as numeric values for specifying axis label text. @Dimitriy Masterov's answer gives good advice. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve References to your files can't be reproduced by us and the detail here about median, mean, min, max is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: The first error was already explained in the answer to your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812591/transform-string-monthly-dates-in-stata

Answer (score 1):

Stata's dates are just integers that have a very flexible display format. When you refer to them by that format, Stata does not really know what you mean. This sort of makes sense, since it would be really hard to write a command to parse all the different possible date formats. For example, "01oct1979", "1/10/79" and "October 1st, 1979" are just 3 ways to refer to the integer the 7213th day since 01jan1960.

Thus the choice is to either

1. refer to particular days or months by number
2. Use a function like `td()` or `tm()`, that map a date or a month to an integer

For example, `td(01oct1979)=7213`. Despite what the documentation says, there's some flexibility in what you can feed `td()`, though that seems like a bad idea. For example, `td(01.10.1979)`, `td(01/10/1979)`, `td(01 10 1979)` all seem to work, but the Euro format `td(10/01/1979)=6949` does not. Don't even think about trying to feed it a string, like `td("October 1, 1979")`: the mogwai will turn to gremlin. The monthly `tm()` is even less omnivorous, so the only choice is really a Henry Ford-esque `tm(1979m10)=237`.

Here's an example that avoid your error message in several ways:

```
clear
input t y
7213  0 
20567 36
end
format t %td
list y t
tsset t
tsline y, tlabel(#2) name(g1, replace) // baseline
tsline y, tlabel(7213 20567, format(%tddd_Mon,_YY)) name(g2, replace) // just change the format
tsline y, tlabel(7213) tlabel(20567 "Today", add) name(g3, replace) // add a second custom label
tsline y, tlabel(7213) tlabel(`=td(23apr2016)' "Today #2", add) name(g4, replace) //add a second custom label without knowing the integer date value
graph combine g1 g2 g3 g4, rows(4) scale(.75)
```

In your code, you are also doing a couple of strange in trying to go from daily to monthly data, both in formatting and the plotting. I would do this like this:

```
clear
input str11 v1
"01/01/2000"    
"01/02/2000"    
"01/03/2000"    
"01/04/2000"    
"01/04/2000"    
"02/01/2000"      
"02/02/2000"    
"02/03/2000"    
"02/04/2000"    
end

gen v2 = _n*rnormal()+23
gen Time_temp = date(v1, "MDY")
format Time_temp %td
gen Time = mofd(Time) 
label variable Time "Time"
format Time %tm
collapse (mean) mean = v2 (median) median = v2 (min) min = v2 (max) max = v2, by(Time)
tsset Time
tsline mean median min max, tlabel(, format(%tm_Mon_YY))
```

Comment: With the example I put in my question, I get a weird graph, with all the dates collapsed on the rhs and the plot on the lhs.

Comment: @user3285148 I don't have your data, so my best guess I'd you have a daily (td) variable but you want monthly (tm) graph. I would collapse first to the month, tsset again, and then plot.

Comment: Without collapsing, I am not sure how your code even runs without complaining about repeated time values when you tsset.